# How to apply styles on Alert.alert() in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have this small segment of code

```
const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
    Alert.alert(
      "Delete from store",
      "Are you sure you want to delete the product?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel",
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => deleteProduct() },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
```

And just wanna apply styles on
**"Delete from store",** this line. Here is what I want to do :

```
style={{
                fontFamily: allFont.SFUI,
                color: allColor.blue,
                fontSize: wp(4.5),
              }}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Alert`,`Toast` are native components that have limited styling on the js side of react native if you are insisting on using those you have to change Native code. my advise is either use a custom alert component or use `react-native-modal`